# Facebook account kit is not working on low android versions

Tags: android, account-kit

I have integrated facebook account kit in my app and it works perfectly fine on devices with higher android versions ( nougat, marshmallw, lollipop etc). On low android api's ( I have tested on huawei h3u10 android 4.2.2 ) it shows the following error when I try to change the country code:

> 04-25 20:31:04.664 3670-3670/com.chaatgadrive.arif.chaatgadrive
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.(ViewGroup.java:5729)
>           at com.facebook.accountkit.ui.PhoneCountryCodeAdapter.getDropDownView(PhoneCountryCodeAdapter.java:273)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner$DropDownAdapter.getDropDownView(AppCompatSpinner.java:650)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner$DropDownAdapter.getView(AppCompatSpinner.java:644)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.DropDownListView.measureHeightOfChildrenCompat(DropDownListView.java:320)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.ListPopupWindow.buildDropDown(ListPopupWindow.java:1300)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.ListPopupWindow.show(ListPopupWindow.java:646)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner$DropdownPopup.show(AppCompatSpinner.java:800)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner.performClick(AppCompatSpinner.java:436)
>           at com.facebook.accountkit.ui.AccountKitSpinner.performClick(AccountKitSpinner.java:61)
>           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17660)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5433)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:924)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:691)
>           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

I have no clue what is going on. Please help.

Comment: I don't think FB supports anything below kitkat.  You probably shouldn't either-  pre-KitKat versions of android only account for 5.2% of the world's devices in use.  Not worth the effort required for backwards compatibility.  Especially if you're targeting the western world.  See https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/  for percentages